# Searching for a GPO's Name in a Windows 7 Event Log?

Tags: windows-7, event-log

Is there a way to search for a particular string (a GPO) in a Windows Event Log Message?  Instead of searching for an Event ID or filtering by event type?

Comment: 'GPOs' don't appear in the Event Log, just events that may be related to their application and results of their implementation.  Can you provide an example of what you're looking for exactly?

Comment: Well basically, if a GPO fails for some reason, I'll know which one isn't working generally...so I just wanted to be able to `grep` the log for it's name that is found in `gpresult /r` to see any related error messages.  Doesn't sound like I'm asking for much...I mean the log has text in it, does it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output of *wevtutil* to a text file as follows:

```
wevtutil qe System /rd:true /f:text > Events.txt
```

This queries the System event log in reverse direction (i.e. most recent events first) and outputs in text instead of XML format. `/c:<n>` can be used to limit the number of events returned.

Now you can search through the event Descriptions in the text file using your favourite editor.

Comment: Thank you!  This is one of the things that's always bugged me about Windows.